# Return an (Anonymous Type with a Function) from a Function - Is There a Better Way?

Tags: vb.net, lambda, anonymous-types

Just so it's known, this question is *mostly* academic, even though I tried to use the concept in a real-world solution. I realize the example is contrived, but I believe the concept is valid.

I want to write some fluent code like this:

```
copy(my_first_file).to(my_second_file)
```

Short, easy to read and understand, perfectly legit. So I define my copy method like this:

```
Private Function copy(FilePath as String) As Object
  Return New With {.to = New Action(Of String)(Function(x) my_real_copy_method(FilePath,x))}
End Function
```

I realize that I can't force an anonymous type into a specific type (like implementing an interface or some other class), and I don't want the overhead of defining a specific class just to match my desired fluent name with the actual method name. So I was able to make the code work like this:

```
copy(my_first_file).to.Invoke(my_second_file)
```

So there is no IntelliSense or type awareness there, and I have to include the Invoke in order to have the method run. How can I get more type safety and exclude the Invoke method, under these constraints:

- Anonymous Type returned from Method
- No additional classes or interfaces
- Preferably, I do not want to pass in another parameter to the copy() method that tells what type to return, unless copy becomes a generic method (but I think that means defining another class/interface, which I don't want to do)

I know that sounds pretty demanding, feel free to call "Bull" if I'm being to difficult!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gabe No. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since VB has no return type inference for generic methods, even where there is no ambiguity, there is **no** way of doing this.

You can have a strongly typed function that returns an anonymous type using generics but you cannot call it with inferred generics, you need to specify them explicitly.

```
Private Function Copy(Of T)(filePath as String, prototype As T) As T
    Return New With { .To = … }
End Function
```

(Naming convention adapted to .NET)

This must be called as follows:

```
Dim nullAction As Action(Of String) = Nothing
Dim proto = New With { .To = nullAction }
Copy(firstFile, proto).To(secondFile)
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was trying to avoid, but I understand what you are saying. I saw Chris Eargle (kodefuguru) do something similar, like:

`copy(Of T)(my_first_file,ReturnFunction As Func(Of Action(Of String),T)) As T`

but I wanted to avoid that. Great explanation, I'll be voting it up. I'll give some time before marking an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry; this is the best I could come up with.  It doesn't meet your requirements....but it does give you the syntax you wanted.

```
Sub Main()
    copy("myFile").To("myOtherFile")
End Sub

Private Function copy(ByVal FilePath As String) As String
    Return FilePath
End Function

<Extension()> _
Public Sub [To](ByVal FromFile As String, ByVal ToFile As String)
    ' Code to really copy goes here
    my_real_copy_method(FromFile, ToFile)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! I see the syntax does look good, I just wanted to do it anonymously if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said your example is contrived, but how about this? It supports method chaining (`CopyTo` [returns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e105zt.aspx) a `FileInfo`), even if it's not [fluent](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). It's built into `System.IO` too.

```
Dim f As New FileInfo("c:\x.txt")
f.CopyTo("c:\y.txt")
```